# how to load thumbnails or any other data in GridView Asynchronously using AsyncTask

Tags: android, gridview, android-asynctask

I have an inner class name ThumbnailCreater inside the activity (this activity receives paths of the videos on the external storage from calling activity ) class which work as a grid view builder.

But the problem is it takes little bit long time to load the the activity layout at the time of

**1** starting it,

**2** coming back to it (thumbnails are clickable and call a new activity to play the clicked thumbnail's video, on pressing back the video playing activity stops but the thumbnail activity don't reappear quickly) and

**3** at the time orientation is changed.

```
class ThumbnailCreater extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<String> pathList;
    Context context;

    public ThumbnailCreater(ArrayList<String> p, Context context) {

        this.context = context;

        pathList = new ArrayList<String>(p);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return pathList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return pathList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return i;
    }


    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView myVid;
        CheckBox picker;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            myVid = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.vid);
            picker = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkIt);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View v, ViewGroup vGroup) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View row = v;
        ViewHolder holder = null;


        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_thumbnail, vGroup, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }



        Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(pathList.get(i),
                MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);


        holder.myVid.setImageBitmap(thumb);

        holder.picker.setText(pathList.get(i));

        if(vidSelected.contains(holder.picker.getText().toString()))
        {
            holder.picker.setChecked(true);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.picker.setChecked(false);
        }

        holder.myVid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ViewGroup thumbNail = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
                CheckBox checker = (CheckBox) thumbNail.getChildAt(1);
                String playIt = checker.getText().toString();

                Intent play = new Intent(context, VideoPlay.class);
                play.putExtra("playIt", playIt);
                context.startActivity(play);
            }
        });



        final CheckBox picker2 = holder.picker;
        picker2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (picker2.isChecked()) {
                    vidSelected.add(picker2.getText().toString());

                } else {
                    for (String s : vidSelected) {
                        if (s.equals(picker2.getText().toString())) {
                            vidSelected
                                    .remove(picker2.getText().toString());

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });



        return row;


}


}
```

I have tried executing `grid.setAdapter(new ThumbnailCreater(pathList, this));` as a AsyncTask but failed to achieve the desired resullt.

Is there any way I can load the thumbnails without making delay like for example in web pages images are loaded (randomly or in order) as they are received from the server without creating hindrance in web page scrolling or navigation.

Comment: put your thumbs in a cache

Comment: use universalimageloader